# Split array of integers based on step size in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, logic

I have written a code to split a array of integers to sub arrays based on step size(it should also include if the step size is empty).  I am sure my logic is not efficient, if anyone has better solution please help me out.

```js
var range = [10, 20, 20, 30, 100, 1000, 3420, 1124, 430, 700, 800,
  35, 39, 12, 5046
]
var rangeSplit = [];

var max = Math.max.apply(null, range);

var bucketSize = max / 25;
var tempArr = []
var tempBucket = 0;
while (tempBucket < max) {
  rangeSplit[bucketSize + tempBucket] = [];
  tempBucket += bucketSize;
}
for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
  var bucket = Math.ceil(range[i] / bucketSize)
  if (rangeSplit[bucketSize * bucket] == undefined) {
    rangeSplit[bucketSize * bucket] = [];
  }
  rangeSplit[bucketSize * bucket].push(range[i])
}

console.log(rangeSplit)
```

Comment: For starters what are expected results? Don't need 5000 elements but basic outline would help

Comment: Is your script working or not? If you have working code and are looking for comments on the style or efficiency, codereview.stackexchange.com is the place to post it. SO is for when you can't make it work and need help.

Comment: Most of the elements that you create in the `while` loop are not array elements. Unless `max` is a multiple of `25`, `bucketSize` will contain a fraction, and array indexes have to be integers. So you're creating named properties instead of array elements.

Comment: You should use `rangeSplit[Math.ceil(bucketSize + tempBucket)]`

Comment: Hi @Barmar, I guess this question should go to code review site, I was looking for a answer whether my solution is good or I need to use JS reduce function, or is there a better standard logic to do it.

Comment: in SO is it possible to move the question or do I need to delete and ask again in code review?

Comment: @DilipRajkumar you need to delete and re-ask on [codereview.se]

Comment: You can use the flag link and request moderators to move it.

Comment: Flagged.  Tnx guys..:)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean with "it should also include if the step size if empty", if you mean that if the step size is empty it should return the original array you can put that condition at the begining of the function, like `if range === ''{ return arr; }`

I wrote it into a function so it will be more generalized,where *arr* is the array you want to slice and *range* is the size of the step

```
    function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, range) {
     var aux = []; //the output

     for (var i = 0; i < (arr.length/range); i++){ // (arr.length/size) is the 
                                                 //number of chunks

      if ((size*i)%i === 0 || i === 0){ 
        aux.push(arr.slice((range*i), (range*(i+1))));
      }
     }
    return aux;
    }

//Try it like 
chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2);
```

Remember arrays are zero-based objects so you need to take the 0 into consideration, that's why I use the condition if `i==0` in the if statement.

[Slice function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) returns a chunk of an array... and it takes a range, just like the function. I hope this is what you where looking for.

Comment: Just to highlight the fact that you were asking if it was a better way ... I think a function similar to this can be a better way, maybe with some extra edge conditions, I'm full aware of the use case, but it works.